# Why does Thread.Join() hang even though the methods in the thread have returned?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a WPF application which uses some library code for authentication which needs to run in a Single-Thread Apartment thread. My approach is to spawn a separate thread to get the authentication object, block until the thread returns and then continue execution. However, in *some* instances my application hangs on Thread.Join(), even though the thread method has returned.

```
    public static ClaimsAuthenticationResult GetClientContextAndCookieCollection(string siteUrl, out CookieCollection cookieResult)
    {
        ClaimsAuthenticationResult authResult = new ClaimsAuthenticationResult();

        // Authentication module needs to run in single-thread apartment state because it uses
        // COM library calls where this is required
        Thread authenticationThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(threadMethod));
        authenticationThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        authenticationThread.Start();

        // Block until thread completion
        authenticationThread.Join(); // Application hangs here

        return authResult;
    }

    private static void threadMethod() {
        // In proper application: set result. But for debugging, return immediately
        return;
    }
```

I am new to both mulththreading and WPF, so I might be doing something stupid. Does anyone see what's going on here? For the record, I don't get the problem if I don't set the thread to STA, but this is a requirement.

[Edit: It appears that the error only occurs when I call the specified method through a validation binding in a WPF view, specifically on a TextBox. When I call the same code in the constructor of the view, the code runs as expected. This would be a viable workaround, but it would be interesting to know what's actually going on here.]

[Edit: The code here has been simplified a bit for debugging - in the production code, the thread method is inside an AuthThreadWorker object which enables returning the result of the authentication process to the authResult object. But these details are as far as I can tell unrelated to the freeze, as the freeze occurs even in the simplified code.]

Comment: Are you 100% sure the thread's methods have finished?

Comment: Try with a debbuger attached and a breakpoint on the 'return;' to check if you really hit it. If so, check on which thread.

Comment: What does thread method actually do, I don't see anything wrong with the posted code?

Comment: @Guillaume: The breakpoint is indeed hit..the thread is an unnamed Worker Thread with ID 4492, managed ID 9 and location identical to the class running the code (ClaimsAuthenticationModule). There are 7 threads running, presumably WPF related. Might be worth noting that the problem does _not_ occur when I instead call the code in the constructor of the WPF View where it is needed. It does occur when I call it from the TextBox Validation code. I guess I could use this as a workaround, but it would be nice to know what's going on. Jodrell: Thread method does nothing in this test case.

Comment: Thread authenticationThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(threadMethod(authResult)));

How does this line even compile? Have you made a mistake when pasting your code? Maybe your "real" threadMethod returns something instead of void?

Comment: @KooKiz: Yes, you're correct that this was an error. I have updated the question with the working code, plus an explanation of the simplifications. The plan was to do this for clarity, but perhaps it backfired.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on your code; it looks as if you're doing it correctly, but the thread is never REALLY terminating. Try setting a breakpoint at the END of the function in the thread; instead of the return keyword (in case you're doing some kind of processing in your return statement that prevents the thread from exiting), as shown in the picture below
[image]. Naming the thread using authenticationThread.Name (or mthread.Name as shown in example) can also aid with debugging. If the thread REALLY terminated, you should see "The thread 'yourname' (0x143c) has exited with code 0 (0x0)." in the Output window of Visual Studio.

Comment: +1 for tip about thread names. The breakpoint placed on the last brace of the thread method is indeed hit, but the debugger does not report "thread exited" when stepping past it. In the same scenario, the debugger _does_ report "thread exited" when the code is called by me and not WPF.

Comment: Since you mentioned WPF, you might call 'onpropertychanged' indirectly, because you set some property value. In this case, the changenotification will wait for the UI thread and also the other way around.