# Visual Studio print thread name in thread exit message

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to debug when my threads are exiting in order to track down an issue.  Per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266536/why-does-thread-join-hang-even-though-the-methods-in-the-thread-have-returned), I've given my threads name.  However, on the exit message in Visual Studio, it still does not print the thread name, only the id like so:

> The thread 0x1ed4 has exited with code 259 (0x103)

Is there a setting or something I'm missing?  I've looked everywhere in VS, but can't seem to find anything.

And maybe I'm just naming it wrong, so here is a small example that shows what I'm talking about:

```
class Program
{
    static ManualResetEvent aThreadMre;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        aThreadMre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        Thread aThread = new Thread(Process);
        aThread.Name = "a_thread";
        aThread.Start();

        /// ...
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        /// ...

        aThreadMre.Set();
        aThread.Join();
    }

    static void Process()
    {
        // Make sure the name was set
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name);

        int counter = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            if (aThreadMre.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
            {
                break;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(++counter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect the problem here is that native (Win32) threads do not really have names; the `Name` field exists in the .Net object. That said, there is a [hack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcb2z8hs.aspx) for Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give this hack a try.

Comment: VS2015 RC displayed a managed thread name automatically on exit but RTM does not. Something in the debugger changed between the two.